# multiple zend pagination controls via ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, pagination, doctrine-orm

Can someone help me achieve multiple zend pagination in a view using ajax. I have managed to achieve single pagination no problem, but now i want to perform more than 1.

this is my setup:-

added to the bootstrap:-

```
public function _initPaginator(){
    Zend_Paginator::setDefaultScrollingStyle('Sliding');
    Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('pagination_control.phtml');   
}
```

'pagination_control.phtml' has been taken from the zend framework manual.

added to the controller:-

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('view', 'html')
                ->initContext();
}
```

added this to the controller action:-

```
public function viewAction()
{

    $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('t')
       ->from('Ajfit\Entity\Ticket', 't')
       ->where('t.engineerFk = :engineer')
       ->orderBy('t.dt', 'desc')
       ->setParameter('engineer', $engineer)
       ->getQuery();

    $paginator =  new Paginator($query);
    $adapter->getIterator();

    $zend_paginator = new \Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    $zend_paginator->setItemCountPerPage(3)
                   ->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));

    $this->view->ticketPaginator = $zend_paginator;
}
```

added this to the view:-

```
<div>
    <div id="ticket-history">
       <?php 
             echo $this->render('profile/view.ajax.phtml'); 
         ?>
       </div> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pagination-control').find('a').live('click', function(e) { 
            var link = $(this); 
            $('#ticket-history').load(link.attr('href'), { format: 'html' }); 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

my 'profile/view.ajax.phtml' script contains:-

```
<?php

     echo '<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tr>';

     foreach($this->ticketPaginator as $ticket){
         echo '<td>' . $ticket->getSubject() . '</td>';
     }

     echo '</tr></table>';
 ?>

<?php 
    echo $this->paginationControl($this->ticketPaginator);
?>
```

This all works fine, however, how would one go about adding a second or third paginator to this view for a different doctrine entity?

Any help would be much apprieciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you have to use multiple `addActionContext` in `init()`

```
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('view', 'html')->initContext();
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('list', 'html')->initContext();
```

and you can continue

add action in controller as `listAction()` for paginator create file as `list.ajax.phtml` also and add required code inside them

Comment: argh right, but what does that do? also if i create a second paginator in the `viewAction` function say like:- `$this->view->replyPaginator = $zend_reply_paginator;` in the view how do i access reference the `echo $this->render('profile/view.ajax.phtml');  ` as this file contains code only code for the `ticketPaginator` and not the new `replyPaginator`?

Comment: can you please give me an example because i'm new to ajax and zend

Comment: i kinda understand what your saying, i think there is an issue though, the pagination links read `/profile/view/name/<name>/page/<x>` and its calling the viewAction all the time, its not calling the `list` action at all, am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved if you manipulate the pagination links to let it call the other action.

For example: In the View Part, you can use the fourth parameter of the `paginationControl` method to define the links which refers to another action. This link should then be called in `pagination_control.phtml`.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer by providing some additional details or a code example?